# Number of files containing a given string

Tags: bash, shell, files, grep

How can I count the number of files (in a directory) containing a given string as input in bash/sh?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`grep -l "string" * | wc -l` will search for "string" in the contents of all files in the working directory and tell you how many matched.

Comment: This won't work if there are a lot of files in the directory, it will throw the error "zsh: argument list too long: grep". Any ideas on how to get rid of this?

Comment: @user16142 grep the directory instead of the files: `grep -lr "string" directory | wc -l` If you don't want recursive search, you can use find with maxdepth option: `find directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -l "string" {} + | wc -l` Note that this second option is slower than grep.

Comment: I have to use `grep -l "string" * |& wc -l `

Answer (score 9):

`grep`s parameter `-l` will only output the filenames which are matching `$PATTERN`, `wc` can count them afterwards.

```
grep -l "$PATTERN" * | wc -l
```

Comment: thanks, but was wondering with a pattern in the file ... sorry for the ambiguous question

Comment: If so, take Wolf's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/pattern_to_look_for/ {s+=1; nextfile;} END {print s}' *
```

Clarification: This looks for the number of files that has the "pattern_to_look_for" in their contents and not in their filenames (like Wag's answer). From your question it's hard to tell what you are looking for.

Comment: But something is missing? because it does not work

Comment: If you look for the string duck you must write it like /duck/ in Awk. Are you doing that?

Comment: yes, the output: awk: read error (Is a directory)

Comment: Wolf's answer will give you duplicates. If there are several occurances of the string you are looking for in one of the files, it will count as extra matches.

Comment: Well, if you have directories in the folder you have to do some extra stuff like replacing the star with something like this `find . ! -name . -prune -type f` (don't miss the backticks). This command only lists the files in the folder.

Comment: you're right, you have a solution?

Comment: Trying to write a complete command, but the backticks gets removed. This is what I intended to do:

awk '/pattern_to_look_for/ {s+=1; nextfile;} END {print s}' `find . ! -name . -prune -type f`

Comment: sorry but the output I get is this: awk: cannot open find (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 3):

This works in most shells including Bash with *any* filename, provided you have access to the GNU implementation of `grep` or compatible:

```
grep -lZe "$pattern" -- * | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

Explanation:

- `grep`'s `-Z` option prints every result with a ␀-byte separator. This character can't be part of a file name, so we can simply count the number of separators to get the number of files.
- To get rid of the other characters in the output, we simply remove everything *except* the ␀ bytes using `tr`.
- Then just count the characters with `wc`.

With any `grep` implementation, you can also do:

```
grep -le "$pattern" ./* | LC_ALL=C grep -c /
```

Here counting the lines with a `/`.

The equivalent with recursive `grep` would be:

```
grep -rle "$pattern" .//. | grep -c //
```

Though that requires support for the non-standard `-r` option, or standardly:

```
find .//. -type f -exec grep -le "$pattern" /dev/null {} + | LC_ALL=C grep -c //
```

(bearing in mind that file paths may end up being longer than the maximum line length supported by your `grep` though).

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Rl "string" pathtofolder/ | wc -l
```

this worked for me and returned number of occurrences of the "string" in specified directory.