# Number of files not containing given string

Tags: shell, files, grep

I read the [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/number-of-files-containing-a-given-string) about how to find out the number of files that contain a certain string. This is possible with `grep -l "string" * | wc -l`.

Is it possible to invert this, finding the number of files **not** containing the target string? I tried adding the `-v` option, but this doesn't seem to output the right result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU or OpenBSD `grep`:

```
grep -L "string" ./* | grep -c /
```

Answer (score 9):

Another POSIX way:

```
c=0
for f in *; do
  [ -d "$f" ] && continue
  { grep -q string || c=$(($c + 1)); } < "$f"
done
echo "$c"
```

By redirecting the command group instead of `grep` alone, we avoid counting as 1 the files which we cannot open (like files which we don't have read permission for, or `*` if there's no non-hidden file in the current directory).

With GNU `grep`, the equivalent would be:

```
grep -d skip -L foo ./* | grep -c /
```

Note that you can't use `wc -l` as filenames can be made of several lines. Having `./` also avoids problems with filenames that start with `-` or **are** `-` (which `--` doesn't work around). Note that it ignores dot files.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a POSIX-compliant way, in case you don't have `grep -L`:

```
for file in *; do
    awk '/string/ { found=1; exit } END{ if(!found) { printf "x" } }' < "$file"
done | wc -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Another POSIX way using only `grep` and `wc`:

```
COUNT_FILES=0
for i in *;do COUNT_FILES=$((COUNT_FILES+1));done
MATCHES=$(grep -l "string" * | wc -l)
NON_MATCHES=$((COUNT_FILES - MATCHES))
echo "There are $NON_MATCHES files not matching \"string\""
```

Comment: Note that it will return 1 if there's no non-hidden file in the current directory. You may also want to skip directories. Another way to count the files and avoid a race condition would be `set -- *`, use `$#` and loop with `for i do ...`. You can't use `wc -l` to count files as filenames can be made of several lines.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much files you want to search through, it's a good advice to take a look at [ack-grep](http://beyondgrep.com/). The reason, because `ack-grep` is a lot faster than good'ol `grep` and the CLI is nearly identical.

`ack-grep -Lur "some string" * | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
( arr=(./*(.N^e_'grep -q PATTERN $REPLY'_)); print ${#arr}; )
```

This saves the names of the files that don't contain `PATTERN` into an array and returns the number of elements in the array. It uses [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `.` selects only regular files (add `D` to include hidden files), `N` turns on `null glob` and the negated (`^`) `e`string: `^e_'grep -q PATTERN $REPLY'_` further deselects the file names for which the shell code between the quotes returns `true`.