# Command to see if a word is in a list of files and output how many files it is in

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

There is a similar question to mine already but mine has a slight difference. I want to see how many files contain each word. When a file has a word then it increments the counter and then continues to the next file. I do not want to know how many times the word appears in each file or the name of the file it appears in, just a counter saying how many files the word is found in my files. For example: I have a directory with 10 files, each file is a recipe and i want to see how many files contain the word 'salt'. After running the command it would output something like : *9 Salt*. Meaning it was found in 9 out of 10 files. I want this for everyword though. So far I have this:

```
 grep -l *| tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | tr -d '[:punct:]' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [Number of files containing a given string](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6648) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -c`

For example

```
kaustubh@hacked:~/test$ cat a
salt
salt
salt
salt
salt

kaustubh@hacked:~/test$ cat b
here sis salt
their is salt
and everywhere is salt

kaustubh@hacked:~/test$ cat c
salt hash
hash salt
sweet salt

kaustubh@hacked:~/test$ cat d
this is line salt
```

Now I want count of word `salt` in files: `grep -c  salt *`

```
kaustubh@hacked:~/test$ grep -c  salt *
a:5
b:3
c:3
d:1
```

Comment: `total=0;for occurance in $(grep -RcshF salt ~/test/); do let total+=$occurance ; done ; echo $total`

Comment: @Security Beast, if i want to use this for every word, do I have to change much in your 'grep -c salt *'. I would need to change the 'salt' part i know.

Comment: just replace salt with you desire word it it will give you count

Comment: I need to only print the total number of files it appears in, so say 5 out of 10 files it would have: 5 salt, meaning salt appeared in five of the files.

Comment: <code>grep -c salt | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'</code> This will give you file names if you just want file count then <code>grep -c salt | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' | wc -l </code> This will give you count

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you recipes folder in in **/home/username/recipes**

Here is a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
dir=/home/username/recipes/
for recipe in $(ls $dir); do
  if [ $(cat $HOME/recipes/$recipe | grep $1) ]; then
   ((count++))
  fi
done
echo "$count $1"
```

Once you've saved the file, you have to make it executable. Do this with:

```
chmod 740 script.sh
```

When you run it, include the argument you are looking for, like this:

```
./script.sh salt
```

If it matches in two files, it will output:

```
2 salt
```

If it matches in three files, it will output:

```
3 salt
```

etc.

Comment: I understand what you are doing and how it works. The problem for me is I am not allowed to submit something which uses loops and if then statements. We have only been shown the commands used in terminals directly. I might have put this in the wrong tag, sorry. Is there a way to use commands like grep that will work ? Thanks very much for all your help.

Comment: This answer is using grep. I couldn't imagine trying to do something like this without loops though, sorry. Way too much expended effort for no reason.

Comment: Thanks man. I agree it is, but for my submission, it is not allowed which is a lot of effort for something which can be done so much quicker with other ways. I will use your answer as a way to further my studies though.

Comment: I am glad you could get some use from it, good luck with your studies.